# Unable to install bundler/gems after upgrading jruby and rubymine version (SSLError)

Tags: ruby, ssl

So recently I was encountering some SSL cert issues so in order to help fix that, I've upgraded our jruby 1.7.4 to jruby 9.1.15 and our RubyMine to 2018.2.1 (team using Ruby Cucumber).

However, now we're facing an issue installing /updating gems and bundler after the upgrade.

We're trying to install from the command prompt:

```
$ set HTTP_PROXY=https://username:password@proxyurl.net:port

$ gem install bundler
```

And receiving the error:

> ERROR: While executing gem ... (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
>
> Received fatal alert: protocol_version

Before setting the proxy the error was:

> WARNING: Unable to pull data from 'https://rubygems.org/':
>   SocketError: Failed to open TCP connection to rubygems.org:443
>   (initialize: name or service not known)
>   (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

1 gem installed

I've even tried going to a Starbucks to avoid the proxy altogether but am still getting a similar error.

Just to add in trying to install bundler in RubyMine itself doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

So somehow I fixed it.. I'm not able to reproduce the fix but that might be related to some foundation problems the fix caused.

Basic steps I used (any of these might help):

Removed versions from gemfile

Trying to install bundler from outside proxy

Install bundler through command prompt and install gems through RubyMine

Change gemfile source to 'http' instead of 'https'

Will update more if I find how to reproduce fix